# Vim Error Format for gfortran compiler

Tags: vim, makefile, fortran

I'm using vim `:make` to compile FORTRAN code using gfortran. I like the functionality of the quickfix window to jump between compile errors. I'm using the errorformat suggested [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Errorformats) for gfortran, which is:

```
errorformat=%E%f:%l.%c:,%E%f:%l:,%C,%C%p%*[0123456789^],%ZError: %m,%C%.%#
```

It detects most of the error. I'd like to add the possibility to handle the following

- Warnings
- Linker errors
- (bonus) Errors involving two locations: (1) and (2)

I've read the documentation, some time ago when I tried to make an errorformat for Intel FORTRAN. It took me a lot of time, for only approximate results. I guess adding the Warning '%W' should not be too difficult since it has the same structure of the error message. For the linker error, I don't know if it's going to work since I use different folders for the sources and objects and use the vpath Makefile functionality.

I enclose below some examples of error messages of the gfortran compiler that I would like to be handled by the errorformat.

Thank you so much for your help

**Error example(handled so far by the errorformat)**

```
folder/file.f90:22.19:

        ini=.false.
         1
Error: Symbol 'ini' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

**Warning example**

```
folder/file.f90:485.12:

        use SomeMod, only: somevar
            1
Warning: Unused module variable 'somevar' which has been explicitly imported at (1)
```

**Linker error example**

```
 /tmp/ccPcF56y.o: In function `MAIN__':
test.f90:(.text+0x8e0): undefined reference to `init_'
../../_build/amod.o: In function `__amod_MOD_dostuff':
amod.f90:(.text+0x3e32): undefined reference to `dothis_'
amod.f90:(.text+0x3e74): undefined reference to `dothat_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Multiple error locations example**

```
file.f90:8.8:

    use AMod
        1
file.f90:231.25:

    call init()
         2
Error: 'init' at (1) has a type, which is not consistent with the CALL at (2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works to some extent

```
set efm=%A%f:%l.%c:,%C,%C\ %.%#,%ZError:\ %m,%ZWarning:\ %m,%f:(%.%#):%m
```

- The multi-line part (%A-%Z) handles errors and warnings on equal footing
- The %C codes is to skip empty lines and lines beginning with a blank
- The link-error format does not take you to the line where the missing funcion is called but it will open the correct file
- I don't see how the multiple error case can be handled with vim errorformat.

This gives in vim

```
:clist
 1 folder/file.f90:22 col 19:  Symbol 'ini' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
 2 folder/file.f90:485 col 12:  Unused module variable 'somevar' which has been explicitly imported at (1)
 4 test.f90: undefined reference to `init_'
 6 amod.f90: undefined reference to `dothis_'
 7 amod.f90: undefined reference to `dothat_'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems the undefined reference is different depending if you use debugging flags (in which case the line number is known). Adding the following to your list will account for both: %f:%l:%m

Answer (score 1):

That's how far I got, it kind of work, but is not really nice

```
set efm=%I%.%#In\ function%m,%I%.%#undefined\ reference\ to%m,%E%f:%l.%c:,%E%f:%l:,%C,%C%p%*[0123456789^],%ZError:\ %m,%ZWarning:\ %m,%C%.%#
```